# How to work with an xslm file with open event from vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have dozens of .xslm files within a folder. From each of these I have to read data from. I would usually use

```
Dim wbk As Workbook
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open("C:\test.xlsm")
```

But in this case it is not possible. The .xlsm files have an `open event` that checks the values with another file and if the data is not identical it closes the file. So I do not want this check to be performed when I access the files from the macro I want to write now.

It would be great if anyone could help me accomplish this?

Comment: You can try opening the second workbook with this line `Application.EnableEvents = False`, make sure you turn it back on afterwards ;)

Comment: This works thanks! You can create an answer for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try opening the second workbook with:

`Application.EnableEvents = False`

Make sure you turn it back on afterwards ;)
This turns off all the Events that normally occur, so it makes sure the `open event` is not executed.